# Angular Lazy Loading throws TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵmod')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, lazy-loading

I'm trying to route to another module from app-routing module in lazy loading mode but it throws this exception that i cannot debug...

My app-routing.module:

```
`{
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: (): any => {
        import('./dashboard/dashboard-routing.module').then(m => { return m.DashboardRoutingModule })
    },
  },
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule {}`
```

My dashboard-routing.module:

```
`const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
   {
  path: 'today',
    component: TodayComponent,
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {}`
```

I'm expecting to get the dashboard component, I tried to load dashboard.module insted of dashboard-routing.module but nothing.

dashboard.module:

```
`@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardComponent],
  imports: [DashboardRoutingModule],
  exports: [DashboardComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule{}`
```

Comment: `loadChildren` should load the actual module where your `DashboardComponent` is declared, not the routing module.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
showing the problem. You could use
[Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)
to create one.

Comment: I'm following a course and he made it like that... i tried to load the dashboard module (where DashboardComponent is declared) but throws the same error...

Comment: Yes, you made that clear inside of the question already, that's why I was asking for a MRE :-)

Comment: I really don't know what was the problem, I rewrote the code in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dfgcyz?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts) with the only change that i didn't add type any (it gave me cannot add blablabla to type void but not anymore lol) to the arrow function (I added the return statement randomly just to try) and now it works, idk